# C - why does atoi

Tags: c

atoi and my function to_integer both correctly turn a string into an int... question is, if i want to find the sum of some numbers via command line arguments, why doesn't it work with to_integer? it works with atoi just fine.

examples and code below :

./a.out 10 15 -> outputs 25 (with atoi)

./a.out 10 15 -> output -74177221 (with to_integer)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int to_integer(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
        sum += to_integer(argv[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);


    return 0;
}

int to_integer(char *str){
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        num = num*10 + ( str[i] - '0' );
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: what happened when you stepped through it in a debugger?

Comment: Because you start at 0, which is the program name, and because your function doesn't properly handle non-numeric input, which `atoi` does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't attempt to convert `argv[0]` as that's the name of the program, not the first argument passed.

So, change to `for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i){`

`atoi(argv[0])` is 0 so that explains why that method works, and it's fortunate that the name of your program does not start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't checking if the character is a digit before subtracting '0' from it and since you're passing it argv[0] which is the name of your program, you're going to get a really odd number for it.

You can check that easily using `isdigit()`. Here is your function updated to do that and exit if it finds a non-digit in the string.

```
int to_integer(char *str){
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        if(isdigit(str[i])) {
            num = num*10 + ( str[i] - '0' );
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```